# Pointer increment and chaining precedence in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I saw this piece of C# code in one of the msdn articles:

```
using System; class Test
{
   public static unsafe void Main() 
   {
      int* fib = stackalloc int[100];
      int* p = fib;
      *p++ = *p++ = 1;
      for (int i=2; i<100; ++i, ++p)
         *p = p[-1] + p[-2];
      for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
         Console.WriteLine (fib[i]);
   }
}
```

I am fairly new to pointers. I understand most of this code, but it would be great if someone can help me understand this line in the above code in more detail:

```
*p++ = *p++ = 1
```

Comment: Good question, since it would not be valid in C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's just a lazy (others would say idiomatic) way to write

```
*p++ = 1;
*p++ = *p++;
```

or, perhaps better to understand:

```
*p=1;
p++;
*p=1;
p++;
```

Comment: Okay! So *p=1, then the pointer moves to the next memory location. Then value at that location is set to 1 and then move to next location. Great!
Thanks mate!

Comment: If you find my answer useful, don't forget to accept it, please.

Comment: yeah.. was just waiting for the 10 mins ;)

Answer (score 2):

In C# `*p++ = *p++ = 1;` is equivalent to:

```
 *p++ = 1;
 *p++ = 1;
```

So the first 2 elements of the array (which is what `p` pointed to originally) are initialized to 1, and p is left pointing to the third element (element 2 using zero-based notation).

As an aside, note that a similar statement in C/C++ would have undefined behavior since the pointer `p` is modified more than once without an intervening 'sequence point'.  However, C# evaluates the expression in a well defined manner.

Comment: yeah.. I wish they hadn't complicated c# so much.. kinda confusing for beginners..

Comment: raze2dust: If it makes you feel any better, use of pointers is entirely non-idiomatic C#. I've never written (or even seen) production code that uses pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break things down:

> `*p++`

This is doing two things: dereference p and a post increment. I.e. show what is at the address `p` now (or assign to it) and *after* increment it (to the next memory location).

So two of these are allowing assignment to the initial and second memory locations (while leaving `p` referring to the third).

C# allows chained assignments: `a = b = 2` assigns 2 to both `a` and `b`.

**NB** don't try this in C or C++, modifying the same thing (`p`) more than once in a single expression is undefined. But C# does define this.

Answer (score 2):

It means that at 0 and 1 positions of allocated memory values set to 1.

For more clear understanding: p* points to some adress of memory, let it be `start`, right to the another adress of memory, which equals `start + sizeof(int)*100`, let it will be `en`d.

In this example to 1 were set elements at `start` and `start + sizeof(int)`. Post increment (`*p++`) means that at first we use `p*` and then it increments with `sizeof(int)` value, the second `*p++` means that we now use `*p + sizeof(int)` and then it increments once more and we have `*p + sizeof(int)*2`.

Answer (score 1):

The first three fib numbers are 0, 1, 1 and that is what the code does. (Zero is skipped here)

It would be more clear to write:

```
*p++=1; // second fib
*p++=1; // third fib.
```

Comment: The first number is not zero in the output of program.

Comment: Then its not the correct fibonacci sequence. As I said, its skipped here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked the note about zero. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. I just wonder why I don't get votes since my answer is quite near to the others (and answers the question imho)

Answer (score 1):

In above code you are generating 100 numbers in Fibonacci series.

on line *p++ = *p++ = 1  , You are initializing first 2 numbers to 1.
i.e. filling number 1 in places pointed by pointer.

Initially pointer is pointing to 0. When you do *p++ this means pointer should be moved ahead one place from where ever its pointing to.

So in this case value at position 1 is assigned to value at poisition 2 which is assigned to value "1". i.e. *p++ = *p++ = 1